# Why is that image distorted when using tf.image.resize?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, tensorflow2.0, image-resizing

I am using Tensorflow 2.4.0 and have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import PIL
image=PIL.Image.open('apple.jpeg')
uiu=tf.image.resize(np.array(image), (224,224))
    
PIL.Image.fromarray(uiu.numpy(),"RGB").save("apple1.jpeg")
```

Supposedly, `apple1.jpeg` should be the same as `apple.jpeg`, but they are different as follows:

`apple.jpeg`:

[image]

`apple1.jpeg`:

[image]

Why is that image distorted when using `tf.image.resize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [`tf.image.resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize): *The return value has type `float32`, unless the `method` is `ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR`, then the return dtype is the dtype of `images`.*

So, the result of `uiu.numpy()` is some NumPy array of dtype `np.float32`, but still has values in the range of `0 ... 255`, which Pillow can't properly save as a meaningful image. So, simply enforce dtype `np.uint8` when saving the image, i.e. instead of

```py
PIL.Image.fromarray(uiu.numpy(),"RGB").save("apple1.jpeg")
```

use something like this:

```py
PIL.Image.fromarray(uiu.numpy().astype(np.uint8),"RGB").save("apple1.jpeg")
```

In general: Why not use [`PIL.Image.resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) in the first place?

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
NumPy:         1.20.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
TensorFlow:    2.4.1
----------------------------------------
```